# SweetAlert2: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue-sweetalert2.js"

Tags: vue.js, import, sweetalert2

Estou tentando usar o swal2 no vue, porém com esta importação estou recebendo o erro

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier
>   "vue-sweetalert2.js". Relative references must start with either "/",
>   "./", or "../".

Estou importando seguindo os passos desse link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sweetalert2

import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2.js' 
 Vue.use(VueSweetalert2);

Já tentei utilizar com ./vue-sweetalert2.js e até especificar o caminho, porém não resolve. Quando tento especificar o caminho recebo o erro (Not Found).

```
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2.js'
Vue.use(VueSweetalert2)

new Vue({
    el: '#signin-form',
    components: {

    },
    data: {
        email: "",
        password: ""
    },
    mounted() {

    },
    methods: {
        showAlert(){
            this.$swal('Olá, você logou com sucesso!');
        },

        processForm(){
            axios({
                method: "POST",
                "url": "http://192.168.0.138:8000/api/loginCandidate",
                data: {"email": this.email, "password": this.password},
            }).then(result => {  
                if(result.data.result){
                    var candidate = result.data.candidate;
                    var token = Object.values(result.data.token);
                    var keys = Object.keys(candidate);

                    localStorage.setItem("token", token);
                    for(var i = 0; i  {
                console.error(error);
            });
       },
    }
})
```

É necessária alguma importação adicional ou componente?

Comment: Adiciona em main.js `import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2.js'
Vue.use(VueSweetalert2)`

Comment: Lá na documentação na primeira parte do uso, já tem mostrando essa informação!

Comment: Já está posto..... 
import privateProps from '../privateProps'
import Vue from '../vue'
import VueSweetalert2 from '../vue-sweetalert2'
Vue.use(VueSweetalert2)

Comment: Deu certo? Seu caminho está correto?

Comment: Continua o erro, o caminho está correto. No caso estou usando o import dentro do _main.js da pasta sweetalert2, da maneira como está no link. Tentei jogar o caminho também.

Comment: `npm i` tentoou?

Comment: tentei :s .....

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, para utilizar após o import você pode fazer assim.

```
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2.js'    
const swal = require('sweetalert2');
```

Dentro dos methods

```
 showAlert(){
    swal.fire({
        type: 'warning',
        title: '...Ops!',
        text: 'agora vai funcionar',
        confirmButtonText: 'Voltar',
        showConfirmButton: true
    });
},
```